# SharePoint Online limitations

Tags: sharepoint-online, limitations

It seems like the content query webpart doesnt't exist in SharePoint online, at least not in my plan (Plan 2, E plans should have it).
I didn't read that until I was looking for it.

Does anybody know about a good overview about the limitations of SharePoint Online?
If something like that doesn't exist, feel free to post here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you gone through these references?

[SharePoint Online: software boundaries and limits](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/sharepoint-online-software-boundaries-and-limits-HA102694293.aspx)

[Microsoft SharePoint Online for Enterprises Service Description.docx](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13602)

You may import a Content Query WP in SharePoint Online, check this out:
[Importing a Content Query Web Part in SharePoint Online](http://www.sjoukjezaal.com/blog/importing-content-query-web-part-office-365/)

Comment: Yes I know about this stuff, what I mean is while working with SP Online I always find stuff that doesn't work but I never read about it before. I mean everybody knows about the sandboxed webparts for example, but things like the content query webpart are difficult to find. Of course when you have a problem and search for a solution you can find information. But is there a real complete list with all limitations of the different SP online plans including missing webparts and so on?